# MVC 4 Clientside regular expressions not firing

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

My normal clientside validation works fine, the moment I add a Regex requirement it does not trigger, not even the required validation triggers.

Model:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$", ErrorMessage = "specify the correct format for the Tel number")]
public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
@{ Html.ValidateFor(model => model.MobileNumber); }
```

I'm using ValidateFor because the validation errors gets displayed in tooltips, this works fine for normal required fields.

Rendered HTML:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="specify the correct format for the Tel number" 
data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$" data-val-required="The Mobile Number field is required." id="MobileNumber" 
name="MobileNumber" type="text" value="0823213456">
```

When I input and invalid value (even leaving it blank) the class attribute of the input field changes to class="text-box single-line valid"

if I remove the Regular expression attribute from the model, the required validation fires correctly clientside

Why won't this Regex validation function as intended?

EDIT:
Bundle Config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js"));
```

Versions:
jQuery Validation Plugin v1.11.1
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2

Comment: I tried your code in my machine and it works fine. When you submit the form with invalid values, is the server side validation kicked in?

Comment: Yes, server side picks up that the Regex fails and returns the validation summary

Comment: it sounds stupid but could you please try to update your client side scripts to the latest ones?

Comment: updated js validate to 1.12 and unobtrusive to 3.1.1 - still not working

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue. Did you ever resolve?

Comment: Anyone find out the issue